# transform Text file to csv with new columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file with a list of names and numbers. 
Example of text file format:

james 500

Katrina 200

kyle 600 etc

I want to create a csv file from this text file with 2 columns, Names and count where name holds names and count hold the numbers. Below is what ive tried so far,

```
import csv

class csvTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.convertToCSV()

    def convertToCSV(self):
        names = []
        with open('BoysNames.txt', 'r') as b_names, open('popular_names.csv', 'w') as out_file, open('GirlsNames.txt', 'r') as g_names:

            for b_lines in b_names:
                b_lines = b_lines.strip().split('\t')
                names.append(b_lines)
            #for g_lines in g_names:
             #   g_lines = g_lines.split('\t')
              #  names.append(g_lines)

            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow(('FirstName', 'Count'))
            writer.writerows(names)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csvTest()
```

I'm not able to split the columns properly it all goes into names. Please help.

Comment: After `b_lines = b_lines.strip().split('\t')` what do you get from `print(b_lines[:5])`? Are you sure you're splitting the input data correctly?

Comment: @user1767754 `writer` will default to a comma, no need to specify.

Comment: @roganjosh ['Spencer 4043']
['Marcus 3794']
['Paul 3787']

Comment: Not sure, csv module is all new to me.

Comment: @roganjosh oh that's true, just verified it.

Comment: So you're not splitting your input data correctly, you're getting each line as a single string. Your data is not tab-delimited I guess.

Comment: @answerSeeker Try to split with (" ") or simply split()

Comment: @AntonvBR AWESOME THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution with pandas. First let's create some sample data:

```
import io

# first let's recreate your file
data1 = '''\
james 500
kyle 600'''

data2 ='''\
Katrina 200'''

file1 = io.StringIO(data1)
file2 = io.StringIO(data2)
```

Now we do the real operation:

```
import pandas as pd

#Let's put them in a list
#This list should in reality be changed to ["path/to/file1", path/to/file2 ...
files = [file1,file2]

# now let's read this data with pandas to a dataframe
names = ["FirstName","Count"]
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f, sep=" ", header=None, names=names) for f in files)

# and output to csv:
df.to_csv("output.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

Result 'output.csv':

```
FirstName,Count
james,500
kyle,600
Katrina,200
```